# Javascript dynamically assign onclick event with parameter in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to send onclick parameters with html onclick

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        document.write(" <tr class='noBorder' onclick='foo(i)' >");
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        document.write(" <tr class='noBorder' onclick='foo(i)' >");
    }
}
```

However, whenever I click on a row, I get back onclick = foo(2)

I've been looking around and found the same question

[Javascript - Dynamically assign onclick event in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040069/javascript-dynamically-assign-onclick-event-in-the-loop)

I was wondering if it is possible to do this with document.write?

Comment: onclick='foo(i)' change the i values to 1 and 0 in the respective conditions

Comment: This condition serves no purpose.

Comment: These are just test cases. Ultimately I will only have one line of document.write(..foo(i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove `i`from the Javascript String:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (i == 1) {
        document.write(" <tr class='noBorder' onclick='foo(" + i + ")' >");
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        document.write(" <tr class='noBorder' onclick='foo(" + i + ")' >");
    }
}
```

**2 Notes**

1. You should inverse your use of ' and "...  using '...' to delimit attributes isn't valid HTML5 (you need `<div style="..."></div>`, not `<div style='...'></div>`)
2. You see `foo(2)` everywhere because that's the last value `i` had.  Your onclick works, but is fetching the last value that `i` had, instead of hardcoding the value of `i` when HTML was rendered.

Comment: if i==1 then you can also say onclick='foo(1)'

Comment: This is the correct way, but then what is the reason for this condition?

Comment: or that if condition should be removed

Comment: These are just test cases. Ultimately I will only have one line of document.write(..foo(i)

Comment: This answer is what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I don't know why the if() clause is there, personally I would have used a switch(), but I didn't want to give a programming lesson here

Comment: @HelpinCodingpls Something like `for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  document.write("<tr class='noBorder' onclick='foo(" + i + ")' >");
}` is the final "desired" code?

Comment: This is just a test case. In my real code, I will have a dynamic array of objects that I will write.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes

Comment: @HelpinCodingpls You should mark your Question as "Answered"

Comment: OK, so the conditionals MAY be desired, just with the/some additional objects base. @SsJVasto, Please refrain from begging for upvotes in this manner.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss No begging occurred, I didn't even ask to upvote my answer, I just said it should be closed (marked as answered).

Answer (score 0):

document.write statements must be run before the page finishes loading

Therefore, you wouldn't want to put document.write into an onclick

If you're trying to modify a page already loaded you'll have to use div tags and use something like:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "bob";
```