# Gving a button a key which is the value of i at this moment

Tags: javascript, for-loop, counter

its a simple Problem but I can't find a good solution.

I have a list of buttons in Javascript and I want to return them their specific  Id.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ButtonsArray.length ; i++){
     ButtonsArray[i].onclick= function(){console.log(i);};}
```

Simple when I click on a Button, he will then take I which is now the ButtonArraylength.

for example :

```
length = 10 , ButtonArray[2] -> 10 , ButtonArray[7] -> 10
```

What is the simplest solution to make every Button return that value of I when the onclick was created `(ButtonsArray[5] -> 5 , 6 -> 6 ,etc.)`

Comment: use `let i` instead of `var i` in the for-loop declaration.

Comment: Something like this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5040146/1985912